# how to remove extra generated row in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have a problem when i m run my code then it show like this`

```
asp:GridView ID="gvdetails"  runat="server" EnableViewState="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="hidden-column">
            Columns >
            asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden-column">

ItemTemplate>
table class="tborder" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="6" border="0" align="center">
thead >
    tr >
        td width="100%" colspan="5" class="tcat">

            Similar Threads
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>

tr class="thead" align="center">
<td class="thead" width="40%">CompanyFName</td>
<td class="thead" width="15%" nowrap="nowrap">CompanySName</td>

</tr>
<tr>
td class="alt2">
<%# Eval("CompanyFName") %> 
</td>
td class="alt2">
<%# Eval("CompanySName") %> 
</td>
</tr>


/table>


/ItemTemplate>


/asp:TemplateField>
/Columns>
/asp:GridView>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? Can you be more specific, can you also format your html

Comment: Which is the extra generated Row. Is it Similar thread ?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to achieve grid view like below.

```
|       Similar threads     |    
| companyFName|CompanySName |
|dxfgf        | sdfsdf      |
|dxfgf        | sdfsdf      |
|dxfgf        | sdfsdf      |
|dxfgf        | sdfsdf      |
|dxfgf        | sdfsdf      |
|dxfgf        | sdfsdf      |
```

Check [ASP.NET Real World Controls](http://aspnetrealworldcontr.codeplex.com/) and for more information check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2006/03/01/real-world-gridview-two-headed-grouping-gridviews.aspx) blog post.

Comment: hi actually all records in our database showing different table but i want only one table whatever image i ve post see that